# Facebook button is loading very slow

Tags: html, facebook

I tried to integrate this Facebook code into my web site

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id))
                        return;
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"></div>
```

I can see the image but it's loading slow. The button is loaded around 2 seconds after the main web site. Is there any solution of this problem?

Comment: it has to download the sdk and stuff. what solution would you expect?

Comment: There are a lot of web sites where Facebook buttons are loading very fast. How they do this?

Comment: you should add an example to your question then - of a fast loading website and your website.

Comment: Have you tried moving that script below the button html? Maybe it's blocking?